# How to load data according to the category from firebase in different-different recycler views

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

i want to upload files on firebase with file name file url and  category and i want to load the data on different different  recycler views according to the categroy in a same activity how can i do that please help and give the your valuable   suggestions

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you have *n* RecyclerView you need to create *n* DatabaseReferences.
After that you should connect them with each other.